# How can I change the color of invisibles in Xcode4?

Tags: xcode, fonts, syntax-highlighting

In Xcode4's preferences, there's the ability to change the colors of your code editor.  One of the things listed at the bottom is 'Invisibles' which one would expect represents spaces and tabs.  However, changing that has no effect.  Is this a bug? (Note, I've never been able to get that to work in any version of Xcode, not just 4.)

**Update**

Well, I found out a little more.  The 'Plain Text' setting affects the characters displayed for invisibles, but the issue is that also includes all brackets, method names, equals signs, etc. so it doesn't look like this one is solvable.  Still, I'm leaving it open in case someone else figures out how to make this work correctly.

**Update 2**

Just a thought... what about modifying the font itself to replace the 'whitespace' character to something smaller/less obvious?  That may work.  Does anyone know which character that is?  I can easily make a new font and share it here.

Comment: What version exactly are you using? I don't see any "Invisibles" reference on Xcode 4.6

Comment: This was an older question.  MAybe they pulled it because they realized it didn't work as expected. (I'm on a PC right now so I can't check, but will update this later if I find anything new out.)

Comment: Just noticed it was asked over a year ago :)

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Xcode has the option to change the color of the invisibles, that (probably) doesn't actually change the color of your spaces. I can't be sure because I have Xcode 4.6.

Try the following:
1. Open the Fonts & Colors preference pane with Command+,
2. Change the color of the invisibles
3. Editor menu > Show Invisibles
4. Check if the color of the symbols representing tabs and spaces match
5. Change the color in the preferences again
6. If the color of the little symbols change, it means I correctly imagined your version of Xcode.

Hope this helps.